# Grep file with two columns as input

Tags: bash, awk, grep, matching

I have a file containing lines like:

```
"ALMEREWEG               ";" 45  ";"      ";"ZEEWOLDE                ";"3891ZN"
"ALMEREWEG               ";" 50  ";"      ";"ZEEWOLDE                ";"3891ZP"
"ALMEREWEG               ";" 51  ";"      ";"ZEEWOLDE                ";"3891ZN"
"ALMEREWEG               ";" 52  ";"      ";"ZEEWOLDE                ";"3891ZP"
"ALMEREWEG               ";" 53  ";"      ";"ZEEWOLDE                ";"3891ZN"
```

and I have a second file containing lines like:

```
3891ZP;50;
3891ZN;53;A
3891ZN;53;B
3891ZN;54;
```

Now I want to grep the first file based on the pattern of the second file, where:

A) the 1st column of the 2nd file is present in the 5th column of the 1st file; and

B) the 2nd column of the 2nd file is present in the 2nd column of the 1st file.

**My question: how to do this?**

**Update 7 July 2013:** I updated file2 format to reflect the third column (number suffices).

Answer (score 2):

One way with `awk`:

```
awk -F';' '
NR==FNR {
  a[$1]=$2
  next
}
{
  line=$0
  gsub(/\"/,"")
  gsub(/ *; */,";")
  if (a[$5]==$2) {
    print line
    line=""
  }
}' file2 file1
```

**Output**:

```
"ALMEREWEG               ";" 50  ";"      ";"ZEEWOLDE                ";"3891ZP"
"ALMEREWEG               ";" 53  ";"      ";"ZEEWOLDE                ";"3891ZN"
```

Comment: Your code is very good - but it fails when there is more than one house number in a particular zip code that needs to be matched (in the first file, second column is house number, fifth column is zip code).  I took the liberty of writing an improved answer - but tip of the hat for you, I would not have been able to do it without your example. And after studying your code I _finally_ (think I) understand how the `NR==FNR` thing works! Upvoting your answer just for that - "it was very useful".

Comment: Thank you @Floris for the kind words. I agree, if the second file has more than one house number for a particular zip then our associative array will definitely fail. I kinda made the assumption that would not be the case based on OP's sample data. :)

Comment: Yes - but I am from Holland and I recognized the type of data. And since OP said in a comment to another question that he had millions of lines in the files, I figured the clash would be unavoidable. Thus the need for an improved answer. Couldn't really show it in a comment, unfortunately. Not sure how well the code will work with such large datasets...

Comment: Well performance might not match that of `perl` but I use `awk` regularly for my work as a system tester and it's quite fast on data parsing and reporting. :)

Comment: I agree `awk` is fast but checking against an array of 5M elements for each row in the table is quite a challenge. I am wondering if there would be a way to speed things up.

Comment: We can delete the array entry after the match had been made to reduce number of entries for next scan.

Comment: I wonder if creating a new file that includes all of file1 but has a `$5;$2` field in it, then using `grep -f` for fast match, and finally stripping out the extra field, would be optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Heavily borrowing from @JS, I offer the following improved solution. The problem with his code is that if you have more than one house number in the same zip code, it will only match the last one.  By creating a composite associative array (if that is the name... basically joining the two fields together), you get around this problem:

Create a file `postcode.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
  FS=";"
}
# loop around as long as the total number of records read
# is equal to the number of records read in this file
# in other words - loop around the first file only
NR==FNR {
  a[$1,$2]=1 # create one array element for each $1/$2 pair
  next
}
# loop around all the elements of the second file:
# since we're done processing the first file
{
  # copy the original line before modifying it
  line=$0
  # take out the double quotes
  gsub(/\"/,"")
  # take out the spaces on either side of the semicolons
  gsub(/ *; */,";")
  # see if the associative array element exists:
  if (a[$5,$2]==1) {
    # echo the original line that matched:
    print line
  }
}
```

Using test file `file1` as follows (I have added a line to show the border case):

```
"ALMEREWEG               ";" 45  ";"      ";"ZEEWOLDE                ";"3891ZN"
"ALMEREWEG               ";" 50  ";"      ";"ZEEWOLDE                ";"3891ZP"
"ALMEREWEG               ";" 52  ";"      ";"ZEEWOLDE                ";"3891ZP"
"ALMEREWEG               ";" 53  ";"      ";"ZEEWOLDE                ";"3891ZP"
"ALMEREWEG               ";" 53  ";"      ";"ZEEWOLDE                ";"3891ZN"
```

And key file `file2` with (again, added a line):

```
3891ZP;50
3891ZP;52
3891ZN;53
```

You will see that JS's code will not match the line with number 50.

But my code does:

```
awk -f postcode.awk file2 file1
```

produces

```
"ALMEREWEG               ";" 50  ";"      ";"ZEEWOLDE                ";"3891ZP"
"ALMEREWEG               ";" 52  ";"      ";"ZEEWOLDE                ";"3891ZP"
"ALMEREWEG               ";" 53  ";"      ";"ZEEWOLDE                ";"3891ZN"
```

Comment: Thank you for this excellent suggestion! I just ran it, but I got zero matches. The reason for this could be that file2 actually has a little bit different format, it's:
3891ZP;52;
3891ZP;53;A
3891ZP;53;B

(the A and B are special suffixes for the house numbers). Could that be the reason for not matching anything (even though it applies to only a few of the lines in the file)? (question updated accordingly)

Comment: The format change should not affect the majority of matches, assuming there are no spare spaces in `file2`. Are you sure you have the arguments the right way around? Will test with updated file format later (when in front of computer, not phone)

Comment: By the way - does my solution at least work on your original (posted) test files?

Comment: I just tested it with your new file - got the same result (although now you only get one match for `53A` and `53B` but I suspect that is what you wanted anyway). Can you post a section of the files that don't work for you, including the exact command you use to process it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `sed` to construct patterns for `grep`:

```
$ grep -Ef <(sed -r 's/(.*);(.*)/^[^;]*;[^;]*\2[^;]*;([^;]*;){2}[^;]*\1/' file2) file1
"ALMEREWEG               ";" 50  ";"      ";"ZEEWOLDE                ";"3891ZP"
"ALMEREWEG               ";" 53  ";"      ";"ZEEWOLDE                ";"3891ZN"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid the files are too big to do this, as I get: "grep: Memory exhausted". file1 has 8,197,924 lines and file2 has 50,0001 lines.

Answer (score 0):

I have splitted file2 into columns using bash's `IFS` and `read`. Then passed the columns to grep:

```
# read line by line
while IFS=$'\n' read line ; do
    # split into columns
    IFS=$';' read -a col <<< "$line"
    # the expression can be refined but should work well as is
    grep -e ' '${col[1]}'  ";".*;.*";"'${col[0]} file1
done < file2
```

Output:

```
"ALMEREWEG               ";" 50  ";"      ";"ZEEWOLDE                ";"3891ZP"
"ALMEREWEG               ";" 53  ";"      ";"ZEEWOLDE                ";"3891ZN"
```

Comment: Is there a difference between `IFS=$'\;'` & `IFS=';'`? I have seen both usages, but don't know if there is a difference.

Comment: @anishsane `IFS=$';'` is ok. It  was just a typo. `\;` is ok as well but not necessary. Will remove it, thx! ;)

Comment: I asked it out of curiosity. Did not mean to correct you ;-) So, there is no difference? (Sadly since it's mainly special characters, I could not google the answer... :O )

Comment: no prob.. the  \ is only meaningful if you are using escape sequences like `\n` or `\t`. Because there is no escape sequence utilizing the `d` the `\` has no meaning. It will being ignored