# How to compare two files and print second file only matching the first file

Tags: python, perl, comparison

I have two files. One has two columns, ref.txt. The other has three columns, file.txt.

In ref.txt,

```
1  2
2  3
3  5
```

In file.txt,

```
1  2  4   <---here matching
3  4  5
6  9  4
2  3  10  <---here matching
4  7  9
3  5  7   <---here matching
```

I would like to compare two columns for each file, then only print the lines in file.txt matching the ref.txt.

So, the output should be,

```
1  2  4
2  3  10
3  5  7
```

I thought two dictionary comparison like,

```
mydict = {}
mydict1 = {}

with open('ref.txt') as f1:
     for line in f1:
         key, key1 = line.split()
         sp1 = mydict[key, key1]

with open('file.txt') as f2:
      for lines in f2:
          item1, item2, value = lines.split()
          sp2 = mydict1[item1, item2]
          if sp1 == sp2:
             print value
```

How can I compare two files appropriately with dictionary or others?

I found some perl and python code to solve the same number of columns in both file.

In my case, one file has two columns and the other has three columns.

How to compare two files and only print matching values?

Comment: somethingl ike `for i in (ref.txt) do grep "^$i" file.txt; done` would come close.

Comment: Is the entry `0 1 2` in `file.txt` considered a match or not? Basically, must the entry in `ref.txt` be found anywhere on a line of `file.txt`, or must the line `start with` the value?

Comment: There is a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17490570/1967396 - it wants to match on certain columns (but the columns are mixed up in that case - a little harder than your problem). The answers are quite interesting and well worth a read.

Comment: Thank you for all comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = pop;
my %hash = map { chomp; $_ => 1 } <>;

push @ARGV, $file;

while (<>) {
    print if /^(\d+\s+\d+)/ and $hash{$1};
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl ref.txt file.txt [>outFile]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

Output on your datasets:

```
1  2  4
2  3  10
3  5  7
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How did you get this output? This code also has an error when I ran it. Number found where operator expected at ref.txt line 1, near "1 2"
 (Missing operator before  2?)
Number found where operator expected at ref.txt line 2, near "2"
 (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
Number found where operator expected at ref.txt line 2, near "2 3"
 (Missing operator before  3?)
Number found where operator expected at ref.txt line 3, near "3"
 (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
syntax error at ref.txt line 1, near "1 2"
Execution of ref.txt aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @ChangWoonJang - My apologies.  I originally had the usage as `perl ref.txt file.txt [>outFile]`, but it should have been `perl script.pl ref.txt file.txt [>outFile]`, and this is now fixed.  Yup!  Just sending those two text files directly to Perl wouldn't work.

Comment: How can we do this using Python? I have no knowledge of Perl.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a revised and commented version that should work on your larger data set:

```
#read in your reference and the file
reference = open("ref.txt").read()
filetext = open("file.txt").read()

#split the reference file into a list of strings, splitting each time you encounter a new line
splitReference = reference.split("\n")

#do the same for the file
splitFile = filetext.split("\n")

#then, for each line in the reference,
for referenceLine in splitReference:

  #split that line into a list of strings, splitting each time you encouter a stretch of whitespace
  referenceCells = referenceLine.split()

  #then, for each line in your 'file',  
  for fileLine in splitFile:

    #split that line into a list of strings, splitting each time you encouter a stretch of whitespace
    lineCells = fileLine.split()

    #now, for each line in 'reference' check to see if the first value is equal to the first value of the current line in 'file'
    if referenceCells[0] == lineCells[0]:

      #if those are equal, then check to see if the current rows of the reference and the file both have a length of more than one
      if len(referenceCells) > 1:
        if len(lineCells) > 1:

          #if both have a length of more than one, compare the values in their second columns. If they are equal, print the file line
          if referenceCells[1] == lineCells[1]:
            print fileLine
```

Output:

```
1  2  4
2  3  10
3  5  7
```

Comment: I have an error for this code like, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    if referenceCells[0] == lineCells[0]:
IndexError: list index out of range     How did you get this output?   Thanks.

Comment: Am I right to guess that the input files you used when you generated this error message contained more lines than the sample data you provided here? There must be one or more rows in the larger file that contain(s) empty cells. I'll edit my answer to show you how to deal with those rows...

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -Ff ref.txt file.txt
```

is enough if the amount of whitespace between the characters is the same in both files. If it is not, you can do

```
awk '{print "^" $1 "[[:space:]]+" $2}' | xargs -I {} grep -E {} file.txt
```

combining three of my favorite utilities: `awk`, `grep`, and `xargs`... This latter method also ensures that the match only occurs at the start of the line (comparing column 1 with column 1, and column 2 with column 2).

Comment: The first grep is simple and works fine for this. Thank you very much.

Comment: "Make things as simple as possible, but not simpler." - usually attributed to Albert Einstein.

Comment: "grep command" has two minor problem. If file.txt contains 111 2 4, this also matching with 1 2 in ref.txt, because the last 1 in 111 and 2 matches '1 2' in ref.txt. Furthermore, if a double space is not the same pattern as a single space between the numbers. It is simple and good method but need to be improved. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is why I gave the second example - to address exactly these problems. It will match only "from the start" (with the `^`) and with variable amount of space (with the `[[:space:]]`). Unfortunately it makes it a bit more complex - but is still fits on a single line.